# Error in adding gif in jFrame

Tags: java, jframe, jlabel, gif

So I've come across one of the solution at stackoverflow for adding gif image to jFrame, now seems like the program accepts the code that I've found at stackoverflow. However, there's probably something wrong with defining the image location, and so I've got both my code that I'm using currently and also the error below, please help!

```
public static void main(String args[])throws MalformedURLException {

URL url = new URL("f:/SDPproject/CheapDealsMobiApp/build/classes/cheapdealsmobiapp/Gif-1");
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
JFrame f = new JFrame("Animation");
f.getContentPane().add(label);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.pack();
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
f.setVisible(true);
}
```

**Note that, error is "Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: f", could that be perhaps the defining of location causing the upset? and if so, what is the solution?**

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to  specify the **Protocol** ,  add  `file://` to the beginning of your file path

## Like This

```
URL url = new URL("file://f:/SDPproject/CheapDealsMobiApp/build/classes/cheapdealsmobiapp/Gif-1");
```

[Check File URI Scheme on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

Comment: Alternative to create URL for Files (less error prone):
 `URL url = new File("f:/SDPproject/CheapDealsMobiApp/build/classes/cheapdealsmobiapp/Gif-1").toURI().toURL();`

Answer (score 0):

Something tells me, what you really want is something more like

```
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(ThisClassName.class.getResource("/cheapdealsmobiapp/Gif-1"));
```

or

```
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(ThisClassName.class.getResource("cheapdealsmobiapp/Gif-1"));
```